# ACF Page Field group incorrectly appearing on Default Wordpress Posts page

Tags: wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I have some text fields I have added to a field group which I intend to show on pages only.

[Screenshots on Field group Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8taD.png)

But they are showing on the standard block editor within posts edit page. Any idea why this may be?

Thanks!

I tried Post Type is not equal to Post but its still showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a validation to each of the rules by pressing the "and" button and adding a validation of "Post Type is equal to page". So the field group will only appear on the post type of pages.